# Angular - How to add Walkthrough to Angular project

Tags: angular

I have a project in Angular-11. I want to add walkthrough that will guide users on the application as shown in the diagram.

[image: walkthrough]

I have never done it before. How do I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ngx-joyride is a great library for this
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-joyride